# Problema la agregar un valor a una variable

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(filas[i] == filas[0]) { // donde filas es = 0 que es el encabezado de mi tabla

      for(var k=0; k <celdas.length; k++){ // donde celdas son el numero de columnas
        s = celdas[k].textContent;
      }        
  }
```

lo que hace es recorrer e numero de celdas que tiene una tabla y recuperar el valor que tiene en la parte del encabezado

la tabla tendría por ejemplo

> | nombre | edad | genero | numHijos |

y cada que recorra el numero de celdas el valor de ese puede ser

```
s= nombre;
s = edad;
s= genero;
s=numHijos;
```

y así poder mandar el parametro, el for si me recorre el encabezado el problema es que lo unico que hace es ponerme el ultimo valor en este caso

```
s=numHijos;
```

Aqui todo el código que utilizo

```
function tabla(){
        var tabla = document.getElementById("datos");
        var filas = tabla.getElementsByTagName("tr"), celdas;
        var suc=0;
        var p=0;
        var s=0;
          for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++){
            celdas = filas[i].children;

              for (var j = 0; j < celdas.length; j++){
                let celda_actual = celdas[j];
                  if(celda_actual.textContent == "-"){
                    celda_actual.id = "f"+i+"- c"+j; 
                    celda_actual.className = "cuadro";
                  }else{
                    celda_actual.id = ""; 
                    celda_actual.className = "";
                  }    
                  if(celdas[1]){
                    var m = celdas[1].textContent;
                  }
                  if(celdas[2]){
                    p =celdas[2].textContent
                  }

                  if(filas[i] == filas[0]) {

                    s = celdas[j].textContent;
                  }        

                  if(celda_actual.textContent == "-" ){
                    celda_actual.textContent = "[f"+i+"- c"+j+"]"+"[m="+m+", p="+p+", s="+s+"]";
                  }  
                }
          }
    }
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: Eso es porque estás reemplazando el valor de la variable s en cada ciclo del segundo for. Como numHijos es la última variable en ser asignada, toma ese valor.

Comment: @GonzaloBustamante edite i pregunta y agrege el codigo que utilizo y modifique algo, ahi a las variables m, p y s les dos el valor de cada uno y si lo hace el problema es la s que me escribe el ultimo valor

Comment: puedes agregar la tabla html y el resultado que esperas en el json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes concatenar la variable s ya que la estás sobreescribiendo.

También no la inicialices, ya que le estás diciendo que es de tipo entero al declarar `s = 0;`

```
if(filas[i] == filas[0]) {

      s += celdas[j].textContent + '&';
}
```

Puedes agregarle un separador. Sólo recuerda al momento de enviar esta variable, quitarle el último separador así:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length-1);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Lo que que quiero haces es mandar el parametro de cada encabezado mediante una llamada de AJAX para realizar una consulta lo parametros serian m= 012 p=123, y s que es el encabezado (cada columna) y a cada uno le quiero agregar la s

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: gracias, me sirvió de algo tu respuesta no del todo pero me dio una idea para solucionarlo .

Comment: Gracias, era difícil lograr con una solución porque no se entendía muy bien el anunciado. Saludos!